# ReadOnly AttachedProperty based on another property

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

How can one create a ReadOnly AttachedProperty that gets its value changed based on another property of the same control?

For instance, let's say that I want to expose a boolean property to tell the UI if there are errors associated with the control. Something that would look like this:

```cs
public class TextBoxAttachedProperties : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasErrorsKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
        "HasErrors",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TextBoxAttachedProperties),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorsProperty = HasErrorsKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static bool GetHasErrors(UIElement element)
    {
        return (...);
    }
}
```

I want to return `true` whenever `Validation.Errors` changes and has any values, so I would need to subscribe it's `CollectionChanged` event. How do I access it in my attached property class?

Comment: Have you considered using a style template that adorns the control and points to validation.errors/errorcontent and puts up a red border or a tooltip on an error?  Then you don't have to have an extra property and it just works off of the data annotations of the class being bound to?

Comment: Hi @Kevin. The question isn't about providing the error info, but rather creating an readonly attached property that gets its value changed base on another. By the way, even not being the core of the question, your approach won't display all the errors. But there's other answers for that. Thank you for your comment tho.

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient context for a good answer to be provided. It's not clear at all how you'd even expect to _use_ this property. The main benefit of attached properties is the ability to use them as a _target_ for a binding in XAML, but that of course doesn't apply for a read-only property. Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you'd expect this to work.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but then again, on your honest opinion, what's the point of ReadOnlyAttachedProperties?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things about dependency properties:

You can't code them like normal properties- with logic in `get` and `set`. `get` and `set` should do nothing other than read/write to the underlying `DependencyProperty`. This is because the WPF binding system itself reads/writes directly to the `DependencyProperty`, bypassing the `get` and `set`. The normal property is just a "wrapper" around the `DependencyProperty`- a shortcut. The same goes for attached properties and their `static` `get` and `set` equivalents.

So your `get` *has* to be:

```
public static bool GetHasErrors(UIElement element)
{
    return element.GetValue(HasErrorsProperty);
}
```

Now, specifically with read-only dependency properties, your declaration is slightly wrong in a key way. `HasErrorsKey` should be **`private`**. Read-only dependency properties are more like properties with `private set`. You generally want the class that defines them to be able to set the value, but not anyone else. Access to `HasErrorsKey` determines who is allowed to set the value of `HasErrorsProperty`.

To set `HasErrorsProperty`, you need to call:

```
element.SetValue(HasErrorsKey, value)
```

Where `element` is the `UIElement` you want to set the value on. Note that you need to pass `HasErrorsKey` in order to set the value, so code that doesn't have access to that field can't set the value. Hence why it should be `private`. If it were public, anyone could set it and so it wouldn't be read-only.

So, putting this all together, you need to have some code *inside* `TextBoxAttachedProperties` that gets a reference to a `UIElement` and attaches to the event(s) the influence your `HasErrors`. Then, in the event handler(s), you can call `SetValue` as above, which will update the dependency property.

To get a reference to the `UIElement` in the first place, it's common to use another attached property, like `IsEnabled`. You would use a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback), to be notified whenever `IsEnabled` is set on an element, then attach the necessary event handlers if it's `true` or detach if `false`. Note: You'd have to make sure `IsEnabled` gets set *before* your other properties are accessed.

Comment: Thank you Keith. I'm still struggling to grasp the biggest issue which is, where to get the reference to the UIElement to be able to attach to the event(s) that influences my HasErrors.

Comment: @cneves I've added some info about that to my answer.

Comment: @cneves If my answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: not exactly, because I don't want to add a 'dummy' attached property just to be able to access the underlying UIElement. It's not logical to me the need of a property where it's single purpose is to enable me to access the UIElement to further expose another property. But if that's the only way of doing it, then it's another talk.

Comment: I understand not wanting a dummy property cluttering things up. Unfortunately, I don’t know of any other way to get the reference. The construction and reading of the attached property are all done internally by the WPF framework and expose no events or callbacks that I can find where you’d be able to step in an calculate your own value. The only place you *can* step in with your own code, as far as I know, is during a set operation. Since your ‘HasErrors’ is readonly, another writable property is the only answer I see.